# Can we define our accessors without an init value?

Tags: kotlin

I want to define my own accessor for a field, like this:

```
var item: Item
    get() {...}
    set(value) {...}
```

I get an error because item is not initialized. I cant add lateinit because I define the get and set methods.

What I can choose is to declare another nullable field, and use that field to implement the item accessors, which is too stupid and redundant.

So I guess there must other ways to implement this requirement...

---

update:

Thanks for you reply.
I think I didnt express it clearly. And After I read the doc multiple times, I think the answer is NO.

My requirement is: Is there an easier alternative way to declare this?

```
private var _table: Map<String, Int>? = null
public val table: Map<String, Int>
    get() {
      if (_table == null)
        _table = HashMap() // Type parameters are inferred
      return _table ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread")
    }
```

We have to declare a nullabe backing property so we can customize accessors and also leave the field uninitialized.

Answer (score 4):

If you declare a property with a backing field, you need to initialize it. If you don't want do initialize it, you can declare custom getters and setters.

```
var item: String
    get() = "my String"
    set(value) {
        log(value)
        //do something with value
    }
```

If you don't have a value to initialize the property with, declare it nullable and initialize it with `null`

```
var item: String? = null
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
        //do something with value
    }
```

If this doesn't match your requirements, please update the question to clarify.